# Flutter: Will Crashlytics still work if I use Dart Code Obfuscation?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I'm using the FlutterFire Crashlytics plugin in my app. It is working fine on both  Android and iOS (I've uploaded the .dysm for iOS etc) and I can see the error stacktraces in the Firebase console.
I am ready to release the app and the Flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate) advises obfuscating the dart code using the following option:

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
```

My question is: Will Crashlytics still show me the stack traces in plain format or will obfuscating the code complicate/change this?

Answer (score 4):

Crashlytics will [still show you](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5815#issuecomment-822568080) the stack traces even after obfuscation. Although for now, an [extra couple of steps](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2644#issuecomment-746217634) might be needed to view the stack traces.

Comment: It says to add "add 4 spaces every line like this". Where should the spaces be added?

Comment: seems to much effort to just read the problem. isnt there a official firebase solution to do this properly without manuel intervention?

Comment: @GraSim I was also confused by that statement at first. I added 4 spaces before each line and it worked